# Non-Facebook-page ads in newsfeed

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to create an off-site ad (creative type 1) and place it in newsfeed? I know this wasn't the case so far and that it's not available via Ad Manager/Power editor, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it via API.

If not, is there a work-around i.e. ability to create an "ad" with title, image and body that can appear in newsfeed but without any Facebook Page? (Although it seems I'm repeating myself).

By the way, when trying to target type 1 creative to "desktopfeed" I'm getting the following error: `{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"There are no valid formats in which your ad will deliver.","code":1487569}}`.
This is merely for people who happen to be googling for this error (as I have before posting this).
And the call that produced it: 
`https://graph.facebook.com/act_xxxxxxxx/adgroups?method=post&access_token=xxxxx&name=testing newsfeed availability&campaign_id=6013832871175&targeting={"countries":["US"],"age_min":13,"broad_age":1,"page_types":["desktopfeed"]}&bid_type=CPC&bid_info={"CLICKS":2}&adgroup_status=ACTIVE&creative={"type":1,"link_url":"http:\/\/www.xxxxxxx.com","title":"testing newsfeed","body":"testing newsfeed","image_hash":"edacffeeb479e931d11eb062decfee7f"}&redownload=1`

Thank you,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All offsite ads in newsfeed need to be related to a Facebook Page, however they do not have to actually be published on the page.

You should create an unpublished page, it's the same as creating a standard page post but just setting `published=1` - e.g.:

```
curl -F 'message=Book your trip to Alaska'\
     -F 'link=http://example.com'\
     -F 'picture=http://imageurl.com/image'\
     -F 'published=0'\
     -F 'access_token=PAGE_TOKEN'\
  https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed
```

Then create a adcreative from this:

```
curl \
-F "name=sample creative" \ 
-F "type=27" \
-F "object_id=ID_OF_POST" \
-F "auto_update=true" \
-F "access_token=_____" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/act_12345678/adcreatives"
```

See the documentation for [unpublished page posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/unpublished-page-posts/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I'm aware of unpublished posts, but was wondering if type 1 creatives can be inserted there. (I'd vote up, but can't do it until I'm 15 in rep)

Comment: Hi Dan, you can target type 1 at "all Facebook" which includes feed, but I don't think they will get much/any distribution